# Java Spring EntityManager HTML auto encoding double quotes

Tags: java, spring, jpa, encoding, entitymanager

```
//shareEntity contains a field with this value: text "quoted text" more text
shareRepository.save(shareEntity);

//DB field:   text &#34; quoted text&#34;  more text
```

I can save double quotes in this text field manually but the above code always replaces " with "

What's the best way to deal with this? Should I just decode html entities when reading from it? Or prevent it encoding the quotes in the first place?

Comment: What DB are you using? Are you sure the table charset is unicode(UTF-8)?

Comment: PostGres and as far as I know it is, yes